# How do I add a named HTTPClient in SQLCLR via AddHTTPClient?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, sqlclr, httpclientfactory

I'm following the Microsoft guide [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#named-clients) on how to added a named HTTPClient to my SQL Server with SQLCLR. It all seems straight forward once the HTTPClient is added and I've even got the code to add, but I cannot figure out WHERE this code is supposed to go:

```
services.AddHttpClient("github", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    // Github API versioning
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    // Github requires a user-agent
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
});
```

Apparently this code is somehow supposed to end up in the `Startup class`. How it ends up there, I don't understand. I can't even find this class.

I tried adding this code to a C# script but of course it complains that it doesn't know what `services` is. I don't even know what it is, so I don't expect the SQL Server to know either...

Can someone point me in the right direction please? I'm completely stuck at this point.

**EDIT**

So I'm struggling because I've misunderstood the way a SQL Server is supposed to bridge a database and an external source. There needs to be a web app between them. The web app handles the HTTPClient, not the database....

Comment: You don't. HttpClient isn't supported in SQLCLR. What you linked to has nothing to do with SQLCLR, it's a guide on using HttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Well that would explain it... I've been told this is the standard way to do things. If it isn't, then what is?

Comment: SQLCLR [can only work with a limited set of assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries?view=sql-server-ver15) that's more or less at the level of .NET 3.5. Frankly, if you need HttpClientFactory, you should create a separate Web API or tool that talks to the database instead trying to call others from inside the database

Comment: That *is* the standard way of doing things for ASP.NET Core web apps. Just not *inside* the database. SQLCLR is useful in very specific scenarios, and calling REST APIs using pooling, retries etc from *inside* the database isn't one of them. Do you want to create a custom type? SQLCLR can do that. A custom calculation function, or a custom aggregation? OK. Async code? No way, it doesn't even know about tasks

Comment: In fact, if you need remote access and have access to SQL Server 2016 and later, it's far easier to use scripts in R or Python scripts than SQLCLR. Again though, it's even easier to run those scripts *outside* the database

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to R or Python due to having to implement this system as a demo in SQL Server Express so that I can justify the purchase of SQL Server Standard. I can't use R or Python as the licencing I have to use is the basic Express one, and not the dev one.

So instead of calling a rest API from inside the database, what do I need to create on the SQL Server? Is it a web service? 

Thanks you've been really helpful here. I've got experience with REST and T-SQL, but bridging the gap is proving quite difficult... :)

Comment: Create any other application that talks to the REST services and the API. Web app, console app, whatever you need. Only *you* know what that is - do you need a web UI, is a command-line OK? Since you looked at an ASP.NET Core articlel, you're probably trying to create a web app. The *same* tutorial shows how to use EF Core to talk to the database

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah a web app seems right. I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: @TP_Dev What is the overall goal of what you are trying to accomplish that this particular piece will help with? I'm not necessarily disagreeing with Panagiotis, but providing the overall context of the request for assistance helps ensure the best possible suggestion(s). P.S. from this point forward, you will need to use someone's `@` name in order to respond so that they get notified. It's only automatic for the person posting the question or answer, or when only 2 people are involved.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I need to pull some data from an external system using HTTP requests, and then merge that data into a SQL Server database. At my last place of work this was done from within the database using SQLCLR and additional assemblies but I want to do it the standard way with HTTPClientFactory. I initially thought I could do this from within the database like before, but apparently not. So now I'm quite confused how the database will use a web app to pull this data when it wants to. Thanks for the tip btw, I'm new to Stack Overflow :)